# What is the role of the 'POS' variable in the Proc CONTENTS OUT= data set?

Tags: sas

I'm using proc contents for a database. When appears the variable description there is a variable name pos, What it means?

```
Member     Num    Variable    Type    Len    Pos

WORK.A     1        x        Num       8     0
```

Also, is there a way to view the number of missings for each variables?

Comment: No, you need to calculate the number of missing manually separately. There are many ways illustrated if you google that. cAn you show the code used to generate that output? Not seeing anything similar from PROC CONTENTS here: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=n05an0gd96r7ggn1qfa1iwxx6dx6.htm&locale=en

Comment: Agreeing with Reeza, Pos stands for position in the SAS file. For your missing for each variable here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Proc-Freq-Missing-Values-all-Fields/td-p/387784. If you have SAS/IML you could also run Rs is.na( object ) or just do summary( object ). I think the R answer is more along the lines of what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when using proc contents with out the are two variables
VARNUM and NPOS which define the position of variables. There is no POS,NUM or MEMBER. Maybe you modified them a little bit. Anyway
VARNUM is and index and defines the logical order. It is used when displaying dataset. NPOS is and offset and defines the physical position in each data row. But be aware that this is an offset so the length of variable play an role having two variables of size 200 the first on might be on position 0 and the second on position 200.